# Unable to configure npm proxy while giving composer network start command

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to setup two org setup using composer 19.8. I gave

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n siemens-supply-chain1 -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem -o npmrcFile=/home/mfgteg/Desktop/fabric-samples/first-network/npmConfig
```

to start the network. Where npmConfig containes :

```
proxy=http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/
https-proxy=http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/
```

i.e my proxy configuration. I tried running a test fabric ccenv image container and configured proxy using npm set inside the bash, and I was able to install composer related npm modules. But again when I tried running the above mentioned command for network start, I am getting error :

```
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-runtime-hlfv1 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
```

Comment: In a two org setup I think you should use the options file for npm on the `composer network install` - before the composer network start.

Comment: yup, it worked. Thanks :)